# MS Charts from Datagridview in VB.Net

Tags: vb.net, winforms, datagridview

Good Day Gurus,

How can I create charts in VB.Net Windows forms from a data present in datagridview using MSChart control?

After creating charts I also want to provide a feature to save the chart to a file.

Any sample project or help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Srini

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim FileDB As New SaveFileDialog()
FileDB.Filter = "Image|*.jpg"
            FileDB.FilterIndex = 3
            FileDB.AddExtension = True
            FileDB.DefaultExt = "Image"
         FileDB.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.OK 
            Chart1.SaveImage(FileDB.FileName, ImageFormat.Jpeg)
```